# What online communities exist to help solo travellers meet up?

Tags: online-resources, hostels, solo-travel, couchsurfing

I've done a few long-termish mostly solo trips now, and you hear about communities like [CouchSurfing](http://www.couchsurfing.org/) and [Warm Showers](http://www.warmshowers.org/) (for cyclists).  However I also really enjoy staying in hostels.  Oddly, there aren't really forum communities on the hostel sites.

It's really quite disappointing when you reach a new hostel only to find it almost empty, when there's a busy fun one down the road.

Are there online resources or communities to find who is going to be at hostel X on a certain date, so you can try and meet up with other travellers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Many people use [couchsurfing](http://www.couchsurfing.org)'s [**groups**](http://www.couchsurfing.org/groups.html?search=1) for this exact purpose!

I'm in the [Georgia](http://www.couchsurfing.org/group.html?gid=112) and [Tbilisi](http://www.couchsurfing.org/group.html?gid=7019) groups and I would say the larger part of the traffic in both groups is travellers wanting to meet up with other travellers at their destination.

Note that you must join each group you wish to read, which of course means you also need to be a member of couchsurfing. (You do not have to be a "verified" member, so you don't have to pay any money.)

Comment: RIP the original HostelWorld groups

Answer (score 3):

It is not directly related to your question but the [www.hostelworld.com](http://www.hostelworld.com/) website is pretty good at judging hostels' atmosphere. I just sort the hostels according to rates and choose the one that is not too expensive. It also helps to read some of the reviews themselves.

I chose the hostel that way when I was in Lisbon and I was mainly sitting inside for the whole day talking with the people and barely seeing the city :)

Comment: I've heard very good things about a certain hostel in Lisbon...

Comment: If it's the same one than you can have a dinner in a home atmosphere there.

Answer (score 2):

You can check out [www.sheroamssolo.com](https://www.sheroamssolo.com) it is an online travel community for females only. There are travel forums and a community hub where messages are posted, a chat room and more.

Comment: Likely the OP is male (with the name Mark....) but I think your link is good. There are many people who will search for travel partners, female as well as male. (+1)